# Java double converts more than 4 decimal points to exponential format and stores the same exponential format in the DB

Tags: java, spring-boot, double, bigdecimal, exponential

I have an entity class(Account) wherein I have the following property

`@Column(name = "balance", precision = 10, scale = 10, nullable = false)`

`Double balance;`

Then in one of my spring services, I'm doing the subtraction of two (double) numbers as follows

```
Account account = accountRepository.findById(1);
Double result = 0.0;
Double amount = 9.99999999;
BigDecimal bdResult = subtract(account.getBalance, amount);
result = bdResult.setScale(8, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).doubleValue();
account.setBalance(result); //It sets the value in exponential format
accountRepository.saveAndFlush(account); //Also in the DB it store in exponential form

static BigDecimal substract(Double balance, Double amount) {
    BigDecimal bd1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(balance);
    BigDecimal bd2 = BigDecimal.valueOf(amount);
    BigDecimal result = bd1.setScale(8, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).subtract(bd2.setScale(8, 
    RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN));
    return new BigDecimal(result.toPlainString().trim());
}
```

Here's the entity(DB) properties, FYI I'm using Oracle SQL
[image]

So when data is persisted into the DB the value is stored in exponential form. I want the value to be stored in a precise format i.e. in non-exponential form.
For e.g. consider

```
double balance = 10.0 //account.getBalance();
double amount =  9.99999999;
//After calling AmountUtility.subtract(balance, amount) the result should be as follows
double result = 0.00000001
```

I want to ensure the same result format is also persisted in the table as I must follow 8-digit decimal precision.

I have been working on finding a solution for it for days but still haven't found it. Would highly appreciate it if someone could help me here.

Comment: NEVER use `float` or `double` for financial calculations.  Please read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and 
[Is Floating Point Broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/18157)

Comment: Read what @JimGarrison posted. Never use floating point types for money or if you need to avoid representation errors. Use Big decimal to avoid these issues in Java and use something different in the DB too.

Comment: What currency does this represent?

Comment: "So when data is persisted into the DB the value is stored in exponential form." - I don't see any evidence for that.

Comment: The code seems to make little sense. If you have two doubles, why fool around with BigDecimal in order to subtract one from the other?  What is the weird BigDecimal-to-String-to-BigDecimal conversion about?  By the way, there's only one in-memory representation of a double-precision value, so 'converts to exponential format' shows misunderstanding of data formats. 1234.56 and 1.23456E+03 are the same value; they only differ when you convert to strings.

Comment: To be clear, and against e.g. @aled 's misleading advice, the _default_ choice for storing financial __amounts__ is `long` - and store atomic units (cent, satoshi, penny, etc). Banks and APIs do not, as a rule, allow you to transfer fractional cents and the like. Calculations often _also_ should be done like this (if you can't transfer half a cent, what point is there to keeping it around locally? It's _better_ to decide how it is to be rounded as you do the operation!). It's a rule that has exceptions. Hence, _by default_, store as longs, usually calculate as longs. Not BD.

Comment: My 50 cent: 1) As others have stated, DO NOT use float/double for currency. 2) Why do you use Auto-Boxing on `Double`s? Mix in `BigInteger` and now your whole code is a big mix of chaos. 3) How can a database or IEEE float store a floating point value in non-exponential form? You do know how floats are represented in binary? 4) If this was a real question with a real problem in the code, you should post a lot more of the code. As your question is based on a gross misconception, this does not apply here, but for future questions please remember that, so we then could trace the actual problem.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Can you please elaborate a bit on the hint **and store atomic units (cent, satoshi, penny, etc).** Do you mean discard, as you later describe? Or store in a separate variable (have one long for Euros and one long for Euro-Cents? Or do you mean to store a cent-based total value?

Comment: Have a single variable, usually of type `long`, which represents the total amount entirely in cents. For example, if a new compuer screen cost 1499,99 you'd write: `long price = 149999;`. Whenever you must render this you use a formatter to render it nicely. This is a method call that does all sorts of things (prepend a currency symbol, take care of inserting a decimal point, possibly replacing a cents part of 00 with a dash, and so on. No data type baked into java is good enough to 'just print' when showing a price to human eyeballs, so you HAVE TO write a formatter for it anyway.

Comment: It's almost always correct to do this (instead of BD) because [A] anything except division can be done just as perfectly in longs as in BD, except for gigantic amounts of cash that exceed `long`'s 2^63-1 limit, [B] division is something BDs also cannot do (try it. Run `BigDecimal.ONE.divide(new BigDecimal(3))` and tell me what happens). Instead, when a finance amount needs to be divided, whatever the cause usually is part of a process that explicitly dictates how to deal with errors. So, do it as you divide, not 'just keep the fractional part around until next week'.

Comment: Here is an example of that: Imagine the bank has a function to take some jointly owned bank account and empty it towards its owners equal to the share. So, you have an account with 1 euro in it, and have to divide it amongst 3 owners, each of which own precisely 1/3. You can trivially give each owner account 33 cents, but what is the fate of the final penny? There is no point (and in fact, it is __not possible with BigDecimal!__) to give each owner a third of a cent. If you round up, the bank could be fleeced. If you round down, that might also cause an issue.

Comment: Perhaps the bank's rule is: Determine using a secure random source one random owner and they 'win' and get the final cent. This avoids any discussion about somebody getting fleeced one cent at a time, is obviously fair, and avoids having to deal with any fractionals. If that's the case, then _the algorithm that empties a jointly held account back to its owners needs to implement this logic_, which is significantly simpler with `long` than with `BD` - it yells at you that you have to think about this, whereas BD insinuates incorrectly (by having a 'divide' and promises of perfection).

Comment: @rzwitserloot Respectfully I disagree. I have used in the far past a long (or equivalent integer types) for financial operations because of historical (existing data formats) and technical reasons, but that doesn't make it a good recommendation and I believe it is an anti pattern. There much better options today unless you have very specific reasons, which were not mentioned in the question.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "stores the same exponential format in the DB"?  You seem to be using numeric types in your database, and those are stored without any kind of format.

Comment: @Aled: " There much better options today unless you have very specific reasons, which were not mentioned in the question." - elaborate. Not BD, surely. I explained how BD gains you nothing. It's as good as longs at everything, except division, where it can't do the job the same way longs can't. Except, BD is slower, unwieldy, and 'lies' - gives you the idea you can 'get away' with fractional cents but sooner rather than later some external system will force you to round your fractionals.

Comment: What prevents of using exactly the same algorithm used with integer types with a BigDecimal? I´m not clear on that. Using a decimal type prevents also confusion (how many decimals has this number?). Let me clarify that I speak based on previous experience in the finance industry many years ago, where I used integers for this purpose many times. I would change all that code by BigDecimal today without a doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//After calling AmountUtility.subtract(balance, amount) the result should be as follows
double result = 0.00000001
```

This shows a serious misunderstanding. Because `0.00000001` **is not a value that `double` could possibly represent**. It simply can't. Mathematically.

Take out a piece of paper. Write down the result, in decimal, of dividing 1 by 3.

You'll find that this job is **impossible**. There's not enough room. You start writing 0.3333333 and never get it quite right.

The reason you **can** do the job when I ask you to write 1 divided by 10, is because in a decimal system, if the divisor can be broken down solely into factors of 2 and 5, it 'works' - you don't get an endless sequence of digits. And 10 is trivially broken down into `2 * 5`, of course.

Computers count in binary. For them, **only** divisors that can break down into just factors of 2, 'work'. A double can **exactly** represent `0.5`, and even `0.125` (that's `1 / 8`, 8 is `2*2*2` and therefore passes muster).

But 0.00000001? No. That is **impossible** to accurately convert to a double for the same reason it is impossible to write 1/3 on a piece of paper in decimal. That is not a number whose divisor is an exponentiation of 2.

So, why does `double d = 0.1;` even compile?

Because the rules state that **all** operations in float/double space **all** silently round to the nearest representable double at *every* step continuously throughout all math.

We can see this blow up in our face real easily:

```
double v = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) v += 0.1;
System.out.println(v == 1.0);
```

Run the above and realize how broken this all gets. **Because that prints, bizarrely, false!** - according to computers, evidently ten times a tenth somehow isn't equal to one.

It's not equal to 1 for the same reason this isn't:

- Write down 1 / 3 on a piece of paper (you estimate and write 0.333333 and then run out of room).
- Do it 2 more times.
- Now I hand those notes to someone else and ask them to tell me the sum of the numbers on the 3 notes.
- They will dutifully write down 0.999999. Not 1.0.
- I then ask a third person if the number on that note is equal to 1.0.

They correctly say: No. It's close, but it is not equal. That's exactly what the system is doing. Make that 0.125 and it does work fine.

That 'silently round to the nearest double' stuff is inherent, cannot be disabled, cannot be controlled, and cannot be queried (you can't ask how big the error was for the previous operation, for example).

### So, DO NOT use double for finance stuff!

Yes, bad news. You have to do some serious refactoring work on your codebase. Most of it has to be reviewed.

The two usual alternate paths involve atomicity and BigDecimal.

#### Atomicity

Atomicity is the simple solution. Store everything as atomic units. So, store `long priceInCents = 420;` instead of `double price = 4.20;`. This 'works' because the vast majority of interactions with external stuff, including not just banks and other applications but also human inputs and human eyeballs, either does not support, or at least strongly prefers not to have to deal with, fractional cents. Instead, these interactions usually dictate a rounding behaviour, and it's just simpler to apply those rules as you run into them, instead of attempting to keep an endless (and endlessly eating more memory!) log of fractional stuff and only rounding when you have to interact with a system that requires it, because at that point you can only go with a global rule ('we round down' / 'we round up' / oh, wait, what do we do with exactly half-a-cent again?).

All currencies have an atomic. Yen has Yen. Bitcoin has Satoshi. Euros and dollars have cents. It's usually, but not always, one hundreth of the standard unit.

#### BigDecimal

That's the one you pick if you must have perfect accuracy. But, because it is perfect, it takes as much memory as it needs (which can be *a lot*), is hard to use and slow, and just outright crashes if you ask it to divide by 3, because computers are finite pieces of paper after all. You can solve that crash by telling it how to round, but then you're **still** rounding. If you're going to round you might as well round on cents and just use a `long` instead.

Don't use BD unless you really know what you are doing.

Now that we've dealt with that

Comment: Using an integer type to represent decimal values has disadvantages. All the conversions need to be done manually, the precision is not preserved with the data (which can lead to confusions for example if a value has 2 decimals and another 3) and the size of the number is limited by the size of the integer type. Using an integer has its uses but just the complexity added makes it not worth in most cases. In Java a BigDecimal has the additional advantage of communicating the intention of the type.

Comment: Finance info __is__ an integer type. It's just cents, not euros. I don't know what "conversions need to be done manually" refers to; the numeric essence of it: No, there is no need to convert anything. If it's about rendering: You have to do that with alternatives just the same. Finance does not _have_ 3 decimals (for currencies that don't). That just leaves 'size'. Yes, if you are planning on representing more than literally 10 quadrillion, longs won't suffice. You think "cannot represent more than 10 quadrillion" is a meaningful disadvantage. Please. BD __does not__ say 'this is money'.

Comment: Some calculations sometimes require a factor of more than 2 decimals. That is a pain to do with integers. It may be 3, 4, 6 whatever. I never needed much more than that. It doesn't say it is money, it says that it has decimals. Why go back to the stone age of programming if we have modern tools?